# Sitecore XM Cloud CM host is incorrect

Tags: xm-cloud

I am encountering an issue during the XMCloud SXA setup, specifically when trying to sync the CLI content. The error message I receive is:

```
CM host is incorrect: https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/management.
Please login with the right cm hostname or manually fix the user.json file
```

However, my instance seems to be working fine, and I can access the Sitecore client using the `https://xmcloudcm.localhost` URL.

Here is my user.json file -

```
{
  "endpoints": {
    "xmCloud": {
      "allowWrite": false,
      "host": "https://xmclouddeploy-api.sitecorecloud.io/",
      "authority": "https://auth.sitecorecloud.io/",
      "accessToken": "########",
      "refreshToken": "########",
      "refreshTokenParameters": {
        "organization": "#####"
      },
      "clientId": "########",
      "variables": {
        "xmCloudMonitoringHost": "https://xmcloud-monitoring-api.sitecorecloud.io/"
      },
      "audience": "https://api.sitecorecloud.io"
    },
    "default": {
      "ref": "xmcloud",
      "allowWrite": true,
      "host": "https://xmcloudcm.localhost",
      "variables": {}
    },
    "local": {
      "ref": "xmcloud",
      "allowWrite": true,
      "host": "https://xmcloudcm.localhost",
      "variables": {}
    }
  },
  "$schema": "./schemas/UserConfiguration.schema.json"
}
```

When I attempt to access `https://xmcloudcm.localhost/sitecore/api/management`, I receive the error message: `{"errors":[{"message":"Authentication required."}]}`. To bypass this authentication issue, I also tried setting `<requireAuthentication> to false` as well.

I encountered this error when running the `up.ps1` file and also when using commands like `dotnet sitecore ser push` and `dotnet Sitecore index schema-populate`.

[image]

I've attempted various troubleshooting steps, including:

- Running docker down followed by docker up.
- Deleting all images and starting from scratch.
- Deleting the user.json file to allow it to be auto-generated.
- Restarting the system.
- Repeating the setup process from the beginning, but the issue persists.

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We were able to identify the root cause of the issue! the issue was because the entry for `xmcloudcm.localhost` was commented out in the **host file**, It prevented the system from resolving the hostname to `127.0.0.1`, resulting in the error you encountered during the XMCloud SXA setup.

By simply uncommenting the entry in the host file (removing the # in front of it), allowed our system to correctly resolve `xmcloudcm.localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like something is missing from the user.json at the end:

```
  },
  "$schema": "./schemas/UserConfiguration.schema.json",
  "defaultEndpoint": "default"
}
```

Add the `defaultEndpoint` to your user.json.
try the pull and see if the error persists:

```
dotnet sitecore ser pull --verbose
```

If error persists, Make sure you are connected to the correct environment:

```
dotnet sitecore connect --ref xmcloud --cm http://xmcloudcm.localhost --allow-write true -n default
```

Try to pull again, if still you have the same error, please share your cli version and config, you can find it in `.config/dotnet-tools.json`